# loading and using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have been using tidyverse for a long time now but over the past few days every time i try to use it i get the following error:

> ** Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.3.4 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.6 is required
> **

I have tried everything. I have uninstalled and reinstalled r, i have updated the packages but I cannot get it to work. I am getting quite desperate at this stage and would appreciate any help possible.

Comment: Do you have an `.Rprofile` file that loads packages automatically when opening R? When you start a fresh R session, what does `sessionInfo()` show.

Comment: Have you tried updating `vctrs` >= 0.3.6?